# Traveling from Riyadh to India via Kuwait

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, kuwait

I am holding Indian citizenship.
Planning to travel from Riyadh to India via Kuwait over stay of 4 hours.
My question is about  that need Kuwait visa or transit visa because I have different PNR number.
Please request you all let me know whether I need visa or not .